# Why does AWS's Application Load Balancer require a custom domain when using HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

If I create a new AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) using HTTP, then AWS will create a load balancer with a randomly assigned domain name. Why can't AWS do the same thing when I create a new ALB using HTTPS? Instead, when creating a new ALB using HTTPS, AWS requires me to provide a custom domain name and custom certs.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that for valid public SSL certificate you require your own domain that you control. You can't register the certificate for the default domain provided by AWS for ALB because this is not your domain.

Having SSL certs is a lot of work, including managing its registration and renewals. I guess AWS does not want to do that, though they provide SSL for CloudFront AWS-provided default domains.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I suppose I'm then wondering why AWS couldn't just provide a certification for that default domain that they provide?

Comment: @johnnyodonnell Its a design decision that AWS made. I guess its not something they want to deal with. Its easier for AWS to let users manage all SSL stuff on the ALB.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html

> To use an HTTPS listener, you must deploy at least one SSL/TLS server
> certificate on your load balancer. The load balancer uses a server
> certificate to terminate the front-end connection and then decrypt
> requests from clients before sending them to the targets.
>
> The load balancer requires X.509 certificates (SSL/TLS server
> certificates). Certificates are a digital form of identification
> issued by a certificate authority (CA). A certificate contains
> identification information, a validity period, a public key, a serial
> number, and the digital signature of the issuer.

When you create a certificate for use with your load balancer, you must specify a domain name.

You could use Amazon's ACM to provision your certs. You will only be charged for the application as mentioned in the docs below - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-billing.html

Comment: I understand this piece - I'm wondering why AWS doesn't just do this automatically for a randomly generated domain name.

Comment: Is there any update or workaround for this? They can provide that for CloudFront but not for ALBs.